# Complex Conditionals and Unreachable Statements

Tags: java, unreachable-statement

I am very new to Java and am having some trouble. I feel like this an easy fix. Basically, I am looking to return a statement if two criteria are met. Below is my attached code.

```
boolean Windy = false;

if (Windy = true) 
  return "It is Windy";
else 
  return "Not Windy";

if (temperature < 30);
{return "Too Windy or Cold! Enjoy watching the weather through the window";
```

Additional errors are being thrown after I try to alter the script, claiming a return statement is required.

Comment: don't attach code, copy paste it in the question, in a code block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code contains several mistakes:

1. The `=` in `Windy = true` should be a `==` instead. `=` is to assign something, and `==` is to check for equality.
2. Because your first `if (Windy = true) return "It is Windy"; else return "Not Windy";` will always return one of the two, the rest of your code below it is unreachable and will never be executed.
3. Even if it was reachable, the trailing semi-colon at the `if (temperature < 30);` should be removed.
4. The `{}`-block inside your method isn't necessary.

I think this is what you are looking for with your code:

```
boolean windy = false;

if(windy){
  return "It is Windy";
} else if(temperature < 30){
  return "Too Windy or Cold! Enjoy watching the weather through the window";
} else{
  return "Not Windy";
}
```

Of course, setting `windy` to `false` hard-coded kinda makes the first check impossible to reach as well. But I assume it's just your example code and in your actual code you retrieve the `windy` as class variable or method parameter.

In addition, since `windy` itself is a boolean, the `== true` is redundant and just `if(windy)` would be enough.

PS: Variable names in Java are best practice to be camelCase, so use `windy` instead of `Windy` in this case.
I've also added the brackets around the if/else-if/else statements. They aren't required and you can leave them out if you really prefer, but it's easier to modify code without making errors later on.

Comment: One final comment: style wise, many people suggest to **never** go without braces. So even when your for/if/... only has **one** statement, you put braces around that. It happens way too often that a second statement gets added, and people forget that it is *outside* of the if/for/...scope.

Comment: @GhostCat Modified as well. I must admit I prefer without brackets personally, but I can defintely agree with your point (especially for new Java developers), so I've added them to the code snippet and the PS at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I checked your image (what I usually don't do) and spotted several issues in your code.

```
public static String getWeatherAdvice(int temperature, String description)
{
  { // REMOVE THIS BRACKET
    if ( Windy = true) // = signifies an assigning a value, not a comparison. Use ==
      return "It is Windy";
    else
      return "Not Windy";

    if ( temperature < 30 ); // Since the above if-else will always return a value, this
    // code can not be reached. Put this if before the previous if-else. Also: remove the ; after the if statement, otherwise, it ends the if, and the return statement might be triggered.
    { // don't put this bracket if you have a ; after the if
      return "Too windy ... ";
    } // don't put this bracket if you have a ; after the if
  } // REMOVE THIS BRACKET
}
```

A corrected version of your code (could be):

```
public static String getWeatherAdvice(int temperature, String description)
{
   if ( temperature < 30 )
    { 
      return "Too windy ... ";
    } 

    if ( Windy == true) // can also be written as: if ( Windy ) 
      return "It is Windy";
    else
      return "Not Windy";    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare criteria using "&&" = and "||" = or:

```
if (Windy && temperature < 30) {
return "it's windy and temperature is <30";
} else if (!Windy && temperature > 30) {
return "Not Windy";
}
```

Comment: Don't use `== true` or `== false`. It is too easy to miss one of the `=`s and change it into an assignment. `Windy == true` is more easily written as `Windy`.